# How to formatstring totalrow in gridex janus

Tags: .net, gridex

i have some problem in gridex janus

1. how to format string the total row in gridex
2. how to set value in totalrow

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As to set the value in total row, you have to set the aggregate function, which I don't know whether you're aware of. Here's an example, for the sake of comprehensiveness.

```
GridEX.TotalRow = InheritableBoolean.True
GridEX.RootTable.Columns("MyColumn").AggregateFunction = AggregateFunction.Count
```

As for the aggregate function to choose, simply select the one you require among those available.

As for formatting the string for the total row, I am still looking for this information myself. I'll update as soon as I get the details.

And by the way, here are some other questions from which you might find the information about the formatting options, here on SO: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gridex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gridex), in case it helps meanwhile.

> **EDIT**

When you wish to customize the total row cells content, you ought to aggregate the summary manually through your GridEX's `DataSource`, for example, or through the `RowCount` property if you simply wish a count.

When you initialize your GridEX control, you have to set the `TotalRow` to the appropriate value as shown above. Then, implement the `FormattingRow` as follows.

```
private void GridEX_FormattingRow(Object sender, RowLoadEventArgs e) {
    var r = e.Row
    if (r.RowType == RowType.TotalRow) r.Cells("MyColumn").Text = String.Format("{0} elements", GridEX.RowCount);
}
```

So, all you have to do is to get a grip on your DataSource, may it be an `IList<T>`, then aggregate according to your needs, then set the `Text` property of the appropriate cell of your total row.

You're done!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

2. Hi! i have same question and find out result:

`GridEX.RootTable.Columns("YourColumnsName").TotalFormatString = "N0"`

0 is odd number

too late but hope can be useful for another person.
:)